# How to connect Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have created a springBoot application and connected to Azure Active Directory using the GraphApi

For example

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Client Credentials, Client Secret, TenantId

```
/users
method() {
    accesstoken() -->> calling AccessToken graphApi and getting accessToken
    user() -->> using above accessToken hitting /getuser graphApi
}

/group
method() {
    accesstoken() -->> calling AccessToken graphApi and getting accessToken
    user() -->> using above accessToken hitting /getgroup graphApi
}
```

Like this I have 20 service methods, please suggest the best way to achieve and share any referenceUrl

Comment: Hi I notice that you unmark my answer. Is there anything unclear or wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `acquireTokenSilently` method to get the access token with MSAL client credentials flow.

And then use this token to call Microsoft Graph endpoints.

```
public static String getUserAccessToken(String[] scopes) {
        if (applicationId == null) {
            System.out.println("You must initialize Authentication before calling getUserAccessToken");
            return null;
        }
 
         Set<String> scopeSet = new HashSet<>();
         
        Collections.addAll(scopeSet, scopes);

        IClientCredential cred = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
        ConfidentialClientApplication app;
        try {
            // Build the MSAL application object for a client credential flow
            app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(applicationId, cred ).authority(authority).build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error creating confidential client: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
         
        IAuthenticationResult result;
        try{
            SilentParameters silentParameters = SilentParameters.builder(scopeSet).build();
            result= app.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join();
        } catch (Exception ex ){
            if (ex.getCause() instanceof MsalException) {
 
                ClientCredentialParameters parameters =
                        ClientCredentialParameters
                                .builder(scopeSet)
                                .build();
    
                // Try to acquire a token. If successful, you should see
                // the token information printed out to console
                result = app.acquireToken(parameters).join();
            } else {
                // Handle other exceptions accordingly
                System.out.println("Unable to authenticate = " + ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (result != null) {
            // System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.accessToken());
            return result.accessToken();
        }
 
        return null;
    }
```

Completed sample [here](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/04/implement-client-credentials-flow-for-graph-java-client/).

Comment: what is the difference using RestTemplate and ConfidentialClientApplication each will execute graph api call and give accessTOken

Comment: @dinesh `RestTemplate` is used to call rest method to get the access token directly. `ConfidentialClientApplication` is the class encapsulated in the Microsoft Graph SDK, which can directly provide you with functions out of the box. Both of them work but the  latter is definitely more convenient.